# How to call a service method inside of the domain in grails?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

I have to call one method of my controller from my domain. I'm trying to find some answer but I don't find anything and I'm not sure if is possible. Sorry, if my question is wrong, but in the requeriments that I have I have to find a solution for this, because I have do it inside of the method beforeInsert() in my domain.

This is the error when I try to run the project:

| Error 2015-12-02 10:59:29,210 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
Message: null id in com.xxxx entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Controller method:

```
def calculate(Integer max){
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        def users= User.findAllByType(null)
        LicenceTypeService.calculate(users) //This call a service
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }
```

In my Domain:

```
protected void callCalculateWhencreateUser(){
        def users= User.find("from User order by id desc")
        LicenceTypeService.calculate(users) //This call a service
    }

def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
        callCalculateWhencreateUser()
    }
```

In my Service:

```
def calculate(def users){

        //logic code

    }
```

Comment: Not sure calling your service statically is right as it might not have been initialized by the grails application properly. Just wire your service into your controller and domain, then call as normal.

Comment: Can you give me a short example of this, please? I'm new in grails..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject of your question is misleading: you say that you need to call a controller method from a domain, but what your code says is that you're trying to call a service method from both domain and controller.

You can't call a controller method from a domain, is conceptually wrong, but also you need a request to call a controller and you don't have it in a domain.

However, what you're trying to do is in fact the way to do it: leave the logic to the service and call it from controller and domain. But you're doing it wrong.

In the controller you need to declare the service, so spring will inject it into your controller, just like this:

```
class MyController {
    def licenceTypeService

    def calculate(Integer max){
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        def users = User.findAllByType(null)
        licenceTypeService.calculate( users )
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }
}
```

You can use the actual type in the declaration of the service property instead of def, but the important thing is that the property name is the "logical name" of the service: the class name but with the first letter in lower case. That way the property will get injected by spring.

You should change the variable "user" for "users", it makes you think that is a single user but the finder you use returns a list of users instead.

On the domain you have to do just a bit more of work. You need to inject the service in the same way, but you need to add it to the "transients" list, so GORM will not try to create a field in the database for it or retrieve it from the database.

Like this:

```
class MyDomain {

    def licenceTypeService

    static transients = [ "licenseTypeService" ]

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
        licenceTypeService.calculate( this )
    }
}
```

And your service would be something like:

```
class LicenceTypeService {

    def calculate( User user ) {
        // perform some calculation
        // do not call user.save() since this will be invoked from beforeInsert
    }

    def calculate( List<User> users ) {
        // If this is performed on several users it should be 
        // done asynchronously
        users.each {
            calculate( it )
            it.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

However, depending on what you do in the calculate method (for a single user) it can be a method of the User class (that's a more OO solution).

Comment: The problem is probably that you're performing a query inside the beforeInsert event. I don't understand what you're trying to do inside the service: you pass a list of users to the calculate method, instead of the user that you're just creating. If what you're trying to achieve is to perform some calculation on all users when a new one is created (dangerous), then you should use a detached system like jms to make that process in a different thread, and invoke that calculation in the save method of your controller or better yet, from the service by adding a "save user" method.

Comment: hmmmm. Ok. How will be to match the user that I'm just creating?? Thanks

Comment: See my edited answer. Not knowing what you do on the LicenceTypeService I can't give you a better approach.